# VARCHAR 512, qué significado tiene?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un trabajo de la U y tengo la siguiente duda, ya que mi profesor escribe esto en el VARCHAR:

```
, NOMBRE_CLIENTE VARCHAR (512)
```

No entiendo por qué 512, si en otra parte había leído que la cantidad máxima de caracteres que acepta VARCHAR son 255 o más bien, el 512 hace referencia a los bytes que pueden tomar los datos en esa columna? De ser así (la segunda) entonces de cuántos caracteres tengo con el formato de 512?

Mil gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL indica lo siguiente:

- Una columna de tipo `VARCHAR` puede declararse de 0 a 65535 *bytes*
- La longitud de esta misma es variable

Cuando se declara una columna de tipo `VARCHAR` del modo siguiente:

```
VARCHAR(255)
```

Estamos hablando de una longitud de máximo 255 caracteres

De manera práctica en **MySQL 8** cuando declaras una columna con este tipo de dato, te va a permitir una longitud máxima de: **16383**, pasando esto el motor va a retornar un mensaje de error como el siguiente:

> Column length too big for column 'nombre' (max = 16383); use BLOB or TEXT instead

Mientras que **MariaDB 10.4** te permite declarar una columna de tipo `VARCHAR` de **65532**, una vez que este límite se supera el motor regresa un error como el siguiente:

> Column length too big for column 'nombre' (max = 65532); use BLOB or TEXT instead

Una vez revisado lo anterior, podemos verificar que si nuestra columna fue declarada con una longitud de **255** caracteres, al tratar de rebasar este límite ingresando 1 caracter mas, obtendremos un error como este:

> Data too long for column 'nombre' at row 1

**Referencias**

- [MySQL VARCHAR datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html)

Answer (score 1):

Si buscas en la documentación de MySQL encontrarás que el máximo de caracteres es 65,535 en versiones mayor o igual a 5.0.3 antes que eso si era 255. Te dejo el link:

http://ftp.tcrc.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/5.0/es/char.html

Comment: Hola Josué. Muchas gracias por la aclaración de la duda!

Comment: @Aprendiz uy súper bien! Qué amable. Creí que más bien lo del VARCHAR no tenía que ver con las versiones, ya que nos dijeron que trabajaban con la última versión, pero muchas gracias por el aporte, de una la guardo en favoritos. :D

Comment: Aún en la última versión el máximo es 65,535 por fila. Cito: "Los valores en columnas VARCHAR son cadenas de longitud variable. La longitud puede especificarse como un valor de 0 a 65.535. La longitud máxima efectiva de un VARCHAR está sujeta al Tamaño máximo de la fila (65.535 bytes, que se comparten entre todas las columnas) y el conjunto de caracteres utilizado."

Comment: @JosueGuol Para las respuestas, se espera un mínimo de calidad. Una respuesta de 3 líneas, siendo una de ellas un elace, no puede considerarse como tal. Mas parece un comentario. ¿ Te has pasado por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para saber como funcionamos ? Especifícamente, [¿ Como escribo una buena respuesta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Me sorprende como se arrastran por unos puntitos, después de una mala actitud alguien decide contestar bien para ganarse la respuesta. Si desde el principio tuvieran esa buena actitud uno no perdería el tiempo.