# Borrar espacio en blanco a la derecha con TRIM() no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_EXPORT . " set nombre = UPPER(TRIM(nombre))");
```

solo borra los espacios en banco a la izquierda, necesito borrar a la derecha también como seria el query

***NOTA: tanto a la izquierda como la derecha tengo en algunos campos hasta 10 espacios en blanco***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependiendo de la base de datos que estás utilizando, tienes los comandos LTRIM (izquierda) RTRIM(derecha) TRIM (ambos lados).

```
MySQL: TRIM( ), RTRIM( ), LTRIM( )
Oracle: RTRIM( ), LTRIM( )
SQL Server: RTRIM( ), LTRIM( )
```

Por tanto (así de primeras) deberías estar borrando todos los caracteres con TRIM() ya que dices que esa query sí está eliminando los de la izquierda.

Puedes comprobarlo haciendo únicamente un select simple

```
select CONCAT("|", UPPER(TRIM(nombre)), "|")  <- así verás si realmente se ha eliminado espacios en ambos lados al seleccionar con TRIM().
```

Según entiendo el problema,

> me da la sensación que en tu base de datos el campo `nombre` esté
>   creado como CHAR(XX). Es decir, de tamaño fijo. Esto hace que al meter
>   cadenas más pequeñás, los espacios que sobran se llenen con espacios.

En los diferentes sistemas de BD existe el [tipo de dato VARCHAR](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/293778/varchar-512-qu%C3%A9-significado-tiene), que sí es variable, y sí modificará por tanto la longitud del mismo si se introduce una cadena más pequeña.

Por tanto, te diría que asegures que tu campo es VARCHAR para confirmar que debería quedar sin espacios.

Comment: es para mysql voy a probar

Comment: Echa un ojo entonces!! https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/09/25/diferencia-entre-char-y-varchar-en-mysql/

Comment: vale muy agradecido si funciona, muchas gracias

Comment: de nada, encantado!!